# Using external Lib in InnoSetup

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I am using an external Library in inno setup which i call via Stdcall.

```
[Files]
Source: ZipLib.dll; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: dontcopy
...
[Code]
function ReadZipEx(archivePath:String; outputPath:String; callback:longword): longword;
external 'ReadZipEx@files:ZipLib.dll stdcall';
```

**since the library has some dependencys i would like to place the library in some directory below the setup.exe and use it without adding it to the [Files].** Is this somehow possible ? i tried it like this:

```
function ReadZipEx(archivePath:String; outputPath:String; callback:longword): longword;
external 'ReadZipEx@ZipLib.dll stdcall';
```

and like this

```
function ReadZipEx(archivePath:String; outputPath:String; callback:longword): longword;
external 'ReadZipEx@/subdir/ZipLib.dll stdcall';
```

but this only results in errors.
I call the library with the help of InnoCallback.dll by sherlocksoftware.

**EDIT**

As supposed by TLama i tried some other solutions:
This will find the first dll but not the dependency.

```
function ReadZipEx(archivePath:String; outputPath:String; callback:longword): longword;
external 'ReadZipEx@{src}\ZipLib.dll stdcall loadwithalteredsearchpath';
```

This results in an error:

```
function ReadZipEx(archivePath:String; outputPath:String; callback:longword): longword;
external 'ReadZipEx@{src}\ZipLib.dll,ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll stdcall loadwithalteredsearchpath';
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Inno Setup binary runs from a temporary folder, you will need to specify the path to your DLL library. If you want to keep your library stored in the same folder as your setup binary package, you can use the [`{src}`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=src) constant to expand there:

```
[Code]
procedure DoSomething;
  external 'DoSomething@{src}\MyLib.dll stdcall';
```

If you want your library search for its dependencies in the same folder (when absolute path is specified), you can add the [`loadwithalteredsearchpath`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptdll&anchor=loadwithalteredsearchpath) option to its import definition:

```
[Code]
procedure DoSomething;
  external 'DoSomething@{src}\MyLib.dll stdcall loadwithalteredsearchpath';
```

The reference describes this option as:

> **loadwithalteredsearchpath**
>
> Specifies that the DLL should be loaded using the Windows flag
>   LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH, which, in essence, causes the loader to
>   search for any dependent DLLs in the directory containing the DLL.

Comment: The setup still searches for my second dll in the temp directory, is there a way to avoid this ?

Comment: Explicit dependencies are defined by comma separated list of file names, hence I missed that note about them. Try the updated suggestion.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem you have. I've created 2 libraries, MyLib.dll and MyDependency.dll and imported the `DoSomething` function just like shows my bottom example here. This function calls a function from MyDependency.dll with no problem. Both libraries reside by the setup binary package. Are you sure you have all libraries on the right place ? Could you try to minimize the problem by making brand new libraries as I did and not use InnoCallback for start ?

Comment: I'll give it a try and give you an answer when i am done

Comment: With a clean new library everything worked fine :) so i guess i have to figure out what the problem with the other library is

Comment: Welcome to DLL hell! :)